# How to use an array on ng-model

Tags: angularjs

This is my code http://plnkr.co/edit/oxtojjEPwkKng9iKkc14?p=preview

And I want to save  object of sport and punctuation in an array, if there are one or more sports selected save it in the array like this:

```
likes[
{sport: 'futball', points: 1}, {sport: 'tennis', points: 1}
]
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep practicing your English a little bit more (you can ask me on the comment section in spanish if you are strugling)

I think what you are trying to do is to have a single select to be able to choose the sport and score,

Html:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="main-container" ng-controller="main" ng-init="darr.dept=dept2">
        <div class="client-area">
            <label fo.table-container tabler="txt">Score</label>
            <input type="text" id="name-txt" placeholder="Assign the score" ng-model="name">
            <br />
            Sport
            <select ng-model="dept" ng-options="deptOpt.value as deptOpt.name for deptOpt in deptList"></select>
            <br />
            <button ng-click="add()">Add Item</button>
            <table id="tab">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="trow">
                        <th>Score</th>
                        <th>Sport</th>
                        <th>Options</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="ar in arr">
                        <td>{{ar.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ar.dept}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button ng-click="del($index)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller('main', function ($scope) {
    $scope.arr = [];
    $scope.deptList = [{
        name: 'Football',
        value: 'football'
    }, {
        name: 'Tennis',
        value: 'Tennis'
    }, {
        name: 'Baseball',
        value: 'baseball'
    }];
    $scope.dept = "football";
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.add = function () {
        this.arr.push({
            name: this.name,
            dept: this.dept
        });
    };
    $scope.del = function (ind) {
        this.arr = this.arr.splice(ind, 1);
    };
    $scope.editStudent = function(student) {
      console.log(student);  
    };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azweig/v5kbsudy/1

Comment: Hey man it is something like that but how can i do that if i have 2 o more selects and points for each one option selected?

Comment: you can use a second array and send a parameter to indicate on the add function if it goes to arr1 or arr2,

the main problem with your code is that you are using same id and binding for the objects

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/v5kbsudy/2/ (you can use only one function as I told you)

Comment: can't i use something like ng-model="arr[$index].name"? if exist more than 2 options?

Comment: the idea of angular is to bind variables to objects, if your idea is to bind it you have to leave the index to the interpreter. if you woudl youse something like that is because you have different arrays inside thoose arrays (did you check the example 2?)

Comment: Sorry for interrupt, but what does it matter if OP have good english skills or not? This is not a "language" forum, this is for code. You don't have to start an answering by pointing bad language skills imho. PS: *struggling, not strugling.

Comment: @FranVerona it was a constructive comment because nobody was answering, on stack sometimes people just give negative votes only because of that (this was one of the cases, and it happened to me as well, I'm not a native English speaker), thanks for the correction :)